# How to change color of selected text in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, themes

How to change background color of selected text in text input fields in Eclipse windows. Please see attached picture: you can barely see what is selected.

I am using Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) under Ubuntu Linux.

[image]

Comment: I've just looked into my eclipse and even though it's on windows I might help you. When you start eclipse you should have a menu "window" within you'll find preferences. There appears a new window and on the left handside you've got a list starting with "general". In front of it is an arrow which can open the section and reveal more options. If it's the same on Ubuntu the first one should be "Appearance" which too you can open and select "Colors and Fonts". Have you tried this so far?

Comment: Sure, I have tried that. But there's no really any relevant option, or at least I can't find it.
Any other idea?

Comment: is this a theme you've installed for eclipse or is it a default one?

Comment: I've installed some themes. But I thing that the one that is selected now is default. Theme is "dark" and colors and font theme is "Classic Theme".

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324184/eclipse-dark-theme-highlight-issue
Or: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/262811/

Comment: No, those are things that you can easily set in colors options, I have already configured such things. But it maybe good idea to ask my question on eclipse forum.

Comment: Sorry I can't help more than this but yes, maybe they'll be able to help you better with this. :)

Comment: I have the same problem. This is NOT a duplicate. The color used is not the same as in the 'Open Windows>Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors' In the Text Editors highligting-color is fine for me, but in the find/replace dialog (e.g. File Search) you can hardly see any color difference for selected text.