# On Eclipse IDE pydev error highlighting tough to read error

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am new to coding,And i recently tried Eclipse(pydev),On dark mode in eclipse when an error occurs the IDE highlights the error with a bright yellow color(background).And the text also get dimmed. I can't edit the error because i cant really read the text,anyone please help me to change this highlighting colour(Background)Please[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5SQP.png)

There is no problem on light theme[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVZ1a.png)

Comment: First Google search result for "eclipse pydev dark mode unreadable": https://stackoverflow.com/a/47917260

Comment: @LukeWoodward "answered Dec 21, 2017"