# I am using devstyle with eclipse and it highlights the parts of the code that is not going to be executed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This issue has been bugging me for a while. I am using devstyle with eclipse and it highlights the parts of the code that is not going to be executed (I think) because of some #if. can someone help me turn it off?

[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Gca.png)
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYZbW.png)

Comment: Hello! Just do confirm this is a DevStyle related issue. Can you switch to Eclipse Dark theme (In Window > Preferences > General > Appearance) and then share a ScreenShot of how it looks there?

Comment: I don't think it's an issue, it's just a setting I didn't know how to turn off, Aaron answer below helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature specific to C/C++ Editors. As indicated on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903951/how-to-make-the-color-theme-inside-ifdef-more-readable-in-eclipse) you can just go to Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor and uncheck "Highlight inactive code".

Cheers!